# не входит в метод LongPress

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-dialog

доброго времени суток,
прошу помогите, никак не входит в метод LongPress. в чем может быть причина ?

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment implements KeyLongPress{

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(getActivity());
        myDialog.setKeyLongPress(this);
        return myDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        textView = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview,null, false);

        return textView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean LongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (textView != null){
            textView.setText(event.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////

```
public interface KeyLongPress {

    public boolean LongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event);
}
```

////////////////////////////

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    private  KeyLongPress keyLongPress;

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDialog(Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
    }

    public MyDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyLongPress != null){
            keyLongPress.LongPress(keyCode,event);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT){
            event.startTracking();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void setKeyLongPress(KeyLongPress keyLongPress) {
        this.keyLongPress = keyLongPress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, что вы реализовали интерфейс, но ничто не вызывает его методов, т.к. слушатель долго нажатия никакой вьюхе не присвоен

Comment: Проблема в том что при длительном нажатии на кнопку пульта должен вызываться метод onKeyDown (но он не вызывается).

Comment: Кажется, вы и этот слушатель реализовали но нигде не назначили

Comment: Default Методы автоматически вызывается диалоговым окном, то есть его и не нужно присваивать

Comment: Это методы жизненного цикла. они вызываются системой, да. Но вот слушатель нажатий сам собою присвоен не будет если его реализовать в классе. Вам надо где-то прописать что-то типа `view.setOnLongClickListener(listener);`

Comment: view.setOnLongClickListener(listener); нигде и не нужно вызывать, так как пользователь не нажимает ни на какой view. он используя пульт нажимает на кнопку ( а не на view ), а тот уже должен вызвать метод onKeyDown.

Comment: А у вас только в этом случае не работает и в других случаях работало? А в доке что пишут? А если в логи что-то из методов вывести до всяких проверок?